# Javascript prototype , __proto__

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I execute below java script code  I get error at "v.dummy();" line , please let me know where am I doing wrong.

```
    function Test()
    {

    }

    Test.prototype.foo = function () {
        console.log('foo');
    }

    var v = new Test();

    v.foo();

    v.__proto__ = function dummy() {
        console.log('__proto__'); 
    };

    v.dummy(); // Uncaught TypeError: v.dummy is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but:

1) when you assign function to a variable, you may omit the name (`dummy`) and  use an anonymous function (without a name). Function name is useless in this case.
And if you do

`var x = function y(){ ... }`

you can call it like this: `x()`, not <del>`y()`</del>

2) `__proto__` should be an object, not a function

usage of `foo` is correct, therefore it works.

You may want to consider reading a good JS book.

Comment: I made below change and it worked 
v.__proto__ = {
            dummy: function () {
                console.log('__proto__');
            }
        };

My assumption was function is also an object in java script. May be as you said i need to read JS good parts.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode Yes, function is an object in js. In your code you can call your function with `v.__proto__()`. But you should NOT do this, because `__proto__` is an inner object used by javascript (to search the prototype chain to resolve methods it cannot find in the object itself). There are a lot more that can be told about prototypes, therefore I recommended a book

Answer (score 1):

`__proto__` is just a reference of an object

[image: IMG]

You can't make it equal a new function, but you can do it like this:

```
v.__proto__.foo = function dummy(){}
```